# How do I interpret these codes generated by IDA Pro?

Tags: c++, c, mfc, decompiler, ida

Hello and Thank you for your time reading into my question. I have been using IDA Pro to decompile a small piece of code that is quite old and was developed in MFC (2003-2004).

I am not able to understand the following instructions which I have seen over and over again:

```
_WORD *Some_Word;
_WORD *Some_Array; 
 Some_Word = Pointer_To_A_WORD + 0x4B6E;
 Some_Array = Pointer_To_Char_Array + 18;
 Some_Condition = *Some_Word & 0xFF03;
```

1. What is the point of **"+ 0x4B6E"** and **"+ 18"** at line 3 and line 4 respectively? They appear throughout my decompiled c code.
2. At line 5, What is **Some_Condition** checking for?

Thank you very much for your time,

Comment: This doesn't make much sense without a context. You should probably show how these values are being used.

Comment: Yes, My apologies, These values are being prepared to be passed to a WriteFile function that sends these data to a serial port. Some_Array is the byte buffer and Some_Condition is used in an IfElse Statement to add something to the byte array.

Comment: There is no way we can help without context. This is just 5 lines of random code in some project we don't know anything about. Reverse engineering very complex and if you're asking this question, then it's probably beyond your range of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer_To_A_WORD is pointer to instance of an object and 0x4B6E is static offset of some field in the struct. most likely it is 0x96DC in ASM code and IDA converted it into 0x4B6E.

You did not tell IDA that ASM code refers struct with Pointer_To_A_WORD so it interprets it as array of unit16's and element located at index 0x4B6E.

so it is essentially some status field with masked non-intresting bits

```
some_status = arr[0x4B6E] &  (SOME_MASK_1 | SOME_MASK_FIELD)
```

most likely you code checks whether some bits of status are set

```
if(Some_Condition){
//then
}
```

If you tell IDA that 0x96DC is offset to the field in struct and Pointer_To_A_WORD is pointer to struct then it will decompile your code into

```
DWORD required_bits = obj->some_status_field & 0xFF03;
```

the same logic applies to Some_Array
it is

```
uint8_t *some_field = &obj2->some_field;
```

Comment: How do you even know this stuff?!  So basically 'Some_Word' is a member of the 'Pointer_To_A_WORD ' struct (or a class/object?)

Comment: well. I already forgot how I learned this stuff. There should be multiple hacker tutorials which explain this science. Also compiling several lines code app and checking it in IDA helps as well. Also knowing how c++ compiler works would help as well with interpretation of asm code and decompilation attempt of IDA.

Comment: I did the exact same thing this evening, I tried decompiling my own c++ app and I realized most of these codes. But what you pointed was very very helpful.